# Образование или образований

Tags: окончания

Скажите, пожалуйста, как будет более правильно: "два рядом расположенных образования" или "два рядом расположенных образований"?

Comment: образования, если образований , то - двух рядом расположенных образований. Хотя я бы подумал над корректностью слова "образование" в данном контексте. Образование - это не объект, это значит что есть что-то рядом. Хотя в медицине используют слово как указание на неисследованные области. А в целом не ясно образование чего?

Comment: Правильно – ‟Два рядом расположенных образования”, потому что это именительный или винительный падеж, а не родительных, при котором было бы ‟двух рядом расположенных образований”

Comment: "Два образования лучше, чем одно". Здесь "образования" - родительный падеж